# How can I see if my ipad 3 has been hacked?

Tags: macos, iphone, ipad, network, ios

does anyone have a clue on how can I see with evidence if someone has been hacked my ipad 3. I had connected it with an iphone 3 in the past, which wasn't mine. Is there any chance they can move into my system and any ideas on how to see that?

Thank you in advance

Comment: What makes you think the iPad has been hacked?

Comment: What signs do you see of it being hacked?

Comment: It hasn't been hacked. (Unless you're explicitly targeted. If so, you won't be publicly asking us, but your consultants.)

Answer (score 3):

There isn't a practical way for your iPad to be hacked and/or for the system to be moved into, at least without physical access or a jailbreak running.

They could, however, get your Apple ID password if it's not particularly strong or if you reuse the same password on multiple websites, and that can give them access to backups, your calendar, location via Find my iDevice, among other things. If you secure your Apple ID and you haven't jailbroken, then you'll be just fine.

It's highly unlikely that you'll ever have your system accessed because of Apple's review process for apps and the sandboxing requirements imposed on them.

Comment: This answer is no longer valid due to multiple unpatched vulnerabilities (including remote code execution) on unsupported apple devices (which as of today also include the iPad3 and iPad mini) that do not run iOS 10 or later.

Answer (score -4):

I am a hacker. As I know, if you have connected your iPad with a iPhone through iCloud with the same Apple ID, someone with your Apple ID can get all your information including password saved in safari/chrome and other details. But still, a hacker cannot "move into your iPad"  like remote control your iPad or delete all your data, there is no exploit for this available. The only evidence of someone "hack" into your iPad is to see if you lost any data or you got some mysterious email sent using your account.

The best way to avoid being "hack" is never tell others your password and often change your password. If you still think your iPad have been hacked, full restore your iPad and use a new Apple ID.

Extra: A group of hacker have developed a technic that can hack your iOS device with a mod charger. So never use a charger that you don't recognise.

Comment: -1 for using uncited (and probably wrong) statements.
-1 for "I am a hacker.", as it makes me facepalm.
+1 for "I am a hacker.", as it makes me laugh.